# Node.js HTTP GET request content type

Tags: node.js, http, rest, get

I am trying to do a GET request from node.js. This request is to a REST server which will access Hbase and return the data. The GET request contains all necessary Hbase info (table, key, column-family etc.) in it. Following is the code.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/table-name/key/column-family',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
  },
};
http.get(url, function(resp){
  console.log("Status: " + resp.statusCode);
  console.log("Header: " + JSON.stringify(resp.headers));
  resp.setEncoding('utf8');
  var completeResponse = '';
  resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
    completeResponse += chunk;
  });
  resp.on('end', function(chunk) {
    console.log(completeResponse);
  });
});
```

My problem is that the response I get is not always an octet-stream as requested. Most of the time data is in valid format with a header like the following.

```
{"content-length":"454","x-timestamp":"1395469504346","content-type":"application/octet-stream"}
```

But, say 1 out of 10 times the response is an XML string with a header like following.

```
{"content-type":"text/xml","content-length":"793"}
```

The status code is 200 in both cases and I am always requesting for an existing key. This behavior is seemingly random and not caused by any particular key.

How do I ensure that the response is always an octet-stream and not XML / JSON?

Comment: The following seems to work.
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/octet-stream'
    }
The content-type is not needed. Can someone please confirm if this is the right way?

Comment: `Accept` will work instead of `Content-Type`. `Accept` is a request header (which you're sending), while `Content-Type` is a response header and thus will come with the response.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you need to set the [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header to specify the content type you expect (accept) in response from the server. Note that you may accept more than one type of response.

The [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header specify the type of what's in the body of the message. It can be set by your client in case of POST/PATCH request, or by the server in its response. On the receiving side, it is used to know how to handle the body content.

For more detail, you can refer to the comprehensive [MDN content negotiation documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation)